# When to use append?

Tags: python

I've recently started programming in Python 3.5.2 (I learned C++ about three years ago but I haven't put that to use since then) and I can't understand the function of 
    '.append()'

Maybe the problem is that I'm not a native english speaker.

Can someone explain this concept to me?

EDIT: thank you. I can't make this code work. Basically, I want the user to input day, month, year and saving them into GDO. What is my mistake?

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk ()
root.title("Calendar")
root.geometry("300x300")

GDO1 = ['Day', 'Month', 'Year']
GDO = []
for w in range (3):

     en = Entry(root)
     lab = Label(root, text = GDO1[w])
     lab.grid(row=w+1, column=0, sticky = W)
     en.grid(row=w+1, column=1, sticky = W)
     GDO.append(en)

buttonGDO = Button (root, text="Submit", command=GDO.append(en) and print   (GDO))
buttonGDO.grid(row=4)


root.mainloop
```

Comment: This really looks a typical RTFM case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a list for example [1, 2, 3]
If you want to add another element use append:

```
list = [1, 2, 3]
list.append(4)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
consider if you have List = [1,2,3,4]
#append function - Adds an item to the end of the list.
>>>L = [1,2,3,4]
>>>L.append(5)
>>>print(L)
>>>[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Answer (score 2):

The append function appends an object to an existing list.

See the documentation: [list.append](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_append.htm)

EDIT:
In your specific example, the issue is not with append. `mainloop` is a function call, so you need to call it like that, with parentheses:

`root.mainloop()`

Answer (score 1):

Append is pretty simple, it just adds, or appends, a value to a list.

```
>>> list = ['one', 'two', 'three']
>>> list
['one', 'two', 'three']
>>> list.append('four')
>>> list
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
```